# MySQL:How to add specified rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Example table

```
+----+---------+--------+-------+
| PK | Comp    | Amount | Class |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
| A1 | Alpha   |  2.00  |  BA   |
| A1 | Alpha   |  2.00  |  BA   |
| B1 | Bravo   |  1.50  |  BA   |
| B1 | Bravo   |  1.50  |  BA   |
| C1 | Charlie |  2.00  |  BC   |
| C1 | Charlie |  2.00  |  BC   |
| D1 | Delta   |  2.20  |  BC   |
| D1 | Delta   |  2.20  |  BC   |
| D2 | Delta   |  1.70  |  BC   |
| D2 | Delta   |  1.70  |  BC   |
| E1 | Echo    |  3.10  |  BD   |
| E1 | Echo    |  3.10  |  BD   |
| E2 | Echo    |  3.00  |  BD   |
| E2 | Echo    |  3.00  |  BD   |
| E3 | Echo    |  2.90  |  BD   |
| E3 | Echo    |  2.90  |  BD   |
| E4 | Echo    |  2.50  |  BD   |
| E4 | Echo    |  2.50  |  BD   |
| E5 | Echo    |  3.10  |  BD   |
| E5 | Echo    |  3.10  |  BD   |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
```

How could I `ADD` the first value of each `PK`? I've been using
    `SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount...GROUP BY Class`

this is what the result looks like.

```
+----+---------+--------+-------+-------------+
| PK | Comp    | Amount | Class | TotalAmount |
+----+---------+--------+-------+-------------+
| A1 | Alpha   |  2.00  |  BA   | 7.00        |
| C1 | Charlie |  2.00  |  BC   | 11.80       |
| E1 | Echo    |  3.10  |  BD   | 29.20       |
+----+---------+--------+-------+-------------+
```

It added all the `Amount`.
I've used `SUM(MAX(Amount)) AS TopAmount` but got error.
I would like to have this table

```
+----+---------+--------+-------+-------------+
| PK | Comp    | Amount | Class | TotalAmount |
+----+---------+--------+-------+-------------+
| A1 | Alpha   |  2.00  |  BA   | 3.50        |
| C1 | Charlie |  2.00  |  BC   | 5.90        |
| E1 | Echo    |  3.10  |  BD   | 14.6        |
+----+---------+--------+-------+-------------+
```

Like this but just the first data of each `PK`

```
+-------------------+-------+-------------+
| Amount            | Class | TotalAmount |
+-------------------+-------+-------------+
| (A1+B1)           |  BA   | 3.50        |
| (C1+D1+D2)        |  BC   | 5.90        |
| (E1+E2+E3+E4+E5)  |  BD   | 14.6        |
+-------------------+-------+-------------+
```

Thank you for your time..

Comment: I can not understand which out put do you want ?

Comment: I've edited my post sir/madam. Hope I elaborated much.

Comment: can you show your query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Replace `t1` with your table name

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(PK SEPARATOR '+'), Class ,SUM(Amount) AS 
TotalAmount FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT PK, Comp, Amount, Class FROM t1) AS t2  
GROUP BY Class;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
select Class ,SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount from 
(select distinct pk,comp,amount,class from have) 
group by class;
```

Comment: @dhie Kindly accept the answer if it helped you solve your query